# Is there a good 32 bit Hash-function to use for idempotence?

Tags: java, hash

We try to implement idempotence. We do not want to process two times the same file. In our process I change the file to a base64 string. I thought about using a Hash-Algorithm to parse this string into a 32 bit Hash-String. I can only use a 32bit Hash-String, since the proccess after mine is expecting only this field length.

I thought about using MD5, but it does not seem like the best solution. I am not sure how an attack will affect the outcome of our process like it's explained here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Can someone help me out with a good Hash-Algorithm or how I can make sure that MD5 is no security problem for my situation?

Comment: Changing the file to base64 bytes, and then hashing that is not good. Better hash the original file data, say with CRC32. Java has methods (java.util.zip?) for that. MD5 as alternative to CRC32 is longer than 32 bits, so would need to be folded again into 32 bits. Though that is probably unavoidable, as CRC32 has cryptographic attack vectors (=is not made for encryption).

Comment: Why would you first convert the file to base64, and then hash it? Just hash the file directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will hash the file. Since I needed to convert it, it was the easiert approach in my enviroment, but I will fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "secure" 32 bit hash. Any 32 bit hash will require at most ~2^32 units of work to find a message that generates a given target hash, and ~2^16 units of work to find 2 messages with the same hash. In fact depending on access patterns it's likely that you will accidentally encounter multiple messages with the same hash. You need to figure out what the consequences of those attacks would be, and if you can't tolerate them then you need a larger hash size or a different design.

If you don't need any security guarantees then md5 truncated to 32 bits will likely meet your needs, but you may find one of the 32-bit hash algorithms in [Guava Hashing](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html) to be simpler to use and better optimised for your use case.